# how to automate creation of xcode target

Tags: xcode

I have an iphone project in which there are supposed to be mutliple targets created from the same code base. The targets have many similar characteristics, but different info.plist, Default.png files, etc..
how can i automate this process of creating new targets from existing target and modify the build setting to reflect changes for new target ?please help

Comment: thanx for replying Paul,i looked into applescript but could not find something to match my needs.i m thinking to create a mac application with some UI where i can choose the code which is to be copied and at the same time i can choose the provisioning profile for the new targets and programatically i change the build setting but as i am quite new to mac application so just confused how to get this method executed.